# Gson - parsing a json that has different field names and number of fields

Tags: java, gson, android

I'm having trouble creating a pojo from this json:

```
"versionAudio": {
    "Simulcast": [
        "English",
        "Japanese"
    ]
},

{
    "Uncut": [
        "English",
        "Japanese"
    ]
}
```

The versionAudio object can contain any number of String arrays and the name can be anything.  I know I can't create a class for versionAudio.  It will have to be an JSONObject that I will pull data out of.  I'm not sure how begin.  I couldn't find any SO questions that relate to this.  Most cases, the name of the field is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versionAudio class should to have one field `Map<String, String[]>`, try use it